# Keras - Cannot constrain output by clipping

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to constrain the output of the final layer by clipping the values of the output layer of a neural network to the [-1, 1] range. However, the clipping does not help in constraining the values. Is there a more effective way to constrain the output?

```
def encoder(self, x_next, x, y, keep_prob):
    x_con = concatenate([x_next, x, y])
    enc1 = Dense(self.encoder_size[0], activation='relu')(x_con)
    drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc1)
    enc2 = Dense(self.encoder_size[1], activation='relu')(drop)
    drop = Dropout(keep_prob)(enc2)
    enc3 = Dense(self.encoder_size[2], activation='relu')(drop)
    mu = Dense(self.latent_dim, activation='linear', name='encoder_mean')(enc3)
    mu_clipped = Lambda(self.clip_val)(mu)
    log_var = Dense(self.latent_dim, activation='linear', name='encoder_log_var', kernel_initializer='zeros')(enc3)
    return mu_clipped, log_var

def clip_val(self, args):
    mu = args
    mu_clip = K.clip(mu, min_value=-1.0, max_value=1.0)
    return mu_clip
```

The output values I am getting range from [-7.1, 7.2] range. How can I constrain the output layer to produce values in the [-1, 1] range? Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you post a minimal test example to show the incorrect results. `mu_clipped` is indeed between [-1,1] in my own test cases. But I'm not sure where you get the output from [-7.1,7.2]. Only see this part, it looks good to me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Problem you should consider to leave the Clipping of the network output to the Activation Function of your last layer: Using a tanh activation ensures y={-1...1}.

Comment: Yes, however, I am regressing. So using a linear function makes the regression work.